# Add HTML markup to div that is added by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an `onclick` function that adds HTML markup (a table) to a specific div with an `id` attribute.

Example:

```
$(‘#someDiv’).html(‘<table id=“userTable”><\table>’);
```

I want to create another function that adds HTML markup to the markup I already added via jQuery.

Example:

```
$(‘#userTable’).html(‘<tr><td>Hello<\td><\tr>’);
```

But, the computer didn’t know the `id` “userTable” and adds nothing to the `table`.

How can I access this `table` from another function and add to its HTML markup?

Comment: Not sure if tha's only a copy/paste issue, but `‘` is not  single quote... Should be `'`. --- This said, there is not enought code/markup posted to figure out about your issue. Please edit with the relevant details. Read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `’` was added by @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @MarcoSanchez: What?

Comment: Yes @LouysPatriceBessette, you edited the question right?

Comment: @MarcoSanchez: Yes... And you can look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55778032/revisions). You will see that I did not add any `’`... So what's your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if "userTable" is a static or dynamic ID. This is what I understand you need

```js
    $(function(){
        $("#btnAddRow").hide();

        $("#btnAddTable").click(function(){

            let targetDiv = $("#targetDiv"),
                new_table = $("" +
                    "<table border='1' id='userTable'>" +
                    "<thead>" +
                    "   <tr>" +
                    "       <th>Column 1</th>" +
                    "       <th>Column 2</th>" +
                    "   </tr>" +
                    "</thead>" +
                    "<tbody></tbody>" +
                    "</table>");

            targetDiv.append(new_table);

            $("#btnAddRow").show();
        });

        $("#btnAddRow").click(function(){

            let targetDiv = $("#targetDiv"),
                userTable = targetDiv.find("#userTable"),
                new_tr = $("" +
                    "<tr>" +
                    "   <td>Something</td>" +
                    "   <td>Something Else</td>" +
                    "</tr>");

            userTable.find("tbody").append(new_tr);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnAddTable">Add Table</button>
<button type="button" id="btnAddRow">Add Row</button>

<div id="targetDiv">

</div>
```